# How to keep track inside recursion - Davis' Staircase

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am attempting the following problem : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-recursive-staircase/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=recursion-backtracking

Below is my code:

```
def stairs(steps, curr, count):
    if curr <= steps:


        for i in [1,2,3]:
            curr = curr + i
            if curr == steps:
                print("Yes")
                count += 1
            stairs(steps,curr,count)
            curr = curr - i

    return count

print(stairs(3,0,0))
```

I think I have performed the recursion correctly however the final value returned in count is 1 which should be 4 in this case.

I have added a print statement in block where I am updating my count, and its printing it 4 times as expected however the value in count is 1 when the recursion ends.

How can I keep track of this count? Or what am I missing here?

Comment: You are not doing anything with return value of recursive function so its output is same as ignoring calls to stairs recursively

Comment: I have no clue how to go about it. Can you help? @VIPER

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it as below. Just assign the recursive calls to your count.

```
def stairs(steps, curr, count):
    if curr <= steps:
        for i in [1,2,3]:
            curr = curr + i
            if curr == steps:
                count = stairs(steps,curr,count+1)

            else:
                count = stairs(steps,curr,count)
            curr = curr - i
    return count
```

P.S. your current function will explode on recursive calls on large inputs. You should optimize your approach.